# multiple websites on one umbraco, xslt macro required?

Tags: c#, javascript, xslt, umbraco

I am very new to Umbraco and have not done xslt or javascripting.  I have more than one website to provide CMS for.  The main contents are same however, the banners will be different. To solve this, I would like to run some macro or code to retrieve the domain name of the website and based on that domain name call the appropriate banner in Umbraco template to be displayed.  Please let me know if it is feasible and how to do it.  If it is not feasible than what is the proper way to do it.

Kind Regards
Brainbox

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways you could do this.

**If the sites are using different templates but the same macro (method 0):**

Add a paremeter to the macro (in the developer section) then update the code accordingly.

Template:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="MyMacro" runat="server" MyParam="Hello, world" />
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/macro/MyParam" />
```

**If the sites are using the same template as well as macro (method 1):**

You can use umbraco's library to retrieve the host name and execute different code based on that. Create a node in the content section for each of the different sites and upload the banners there, then reference them in the XSLT via their respective node IDs

XSLT:

```
<!-- this gets the domain name -->
<xsl:variable name="domainName">
    <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestServerVariables('HTTP_HOST')" />
</xsl:variable>

<!-- determine which banner to show -->
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$domainName = 'www.websiteone.com'">

        <!-- get the node for website one -->
        <xsl:variable name="websiteOneHeaderNodeId" select="1001" />
        <xsl:variable name="websiteOneHeaderNode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($websiteOneHeaderNodeId)" />

        <!-- display the banner for website one -->
        <img src="{$websiteOneHeaderNode/banner}" />

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$domainName = 'www.websitetwo.com'">

        <!-- get the node for website two -->
        <xsl:variable name="websiteTwoHeaderNodeId" select="1002" />
        <xsl:variable name="websiteTwoHeaderNode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($websiteTwoHeaderNodeId)" />

        <!-- display the banner for website two -->
        <img src="{$websiteTwoHeaderNode/banner}" />    

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

        <!-- display the default banner -->
        <img src="/media/1001/defaultBanner.jpg" />

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**If the sites are using the same template as well as macro (method 2):**

This way is a bit cleaner and utilises what Umbraco is great for. I'd recommend adding a property to the document type that represents the root node of each of the sites. Let's say this document type's alias is `Site` and property's alias is `bannerUrl`. You can then upload a different banner to each of the `Site`'s content node and then access it in the XSLT. Depending on which page the user is currently viewing, even subpages with different document types (and assuming it has your macro) the following XSLT will find the appropriate `bannerUrl` dependant on which `Site` node it is under.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::Site/bannerUrl" />
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help.I was trying to use method 2 however, it did not work for me as only the header & footer of websites will be different and I need to have same content on the page.Therefore,I used method 1.Now,I have made 2 folders for different websites, where i am storing different banners for header and different text for footer(for different websites obviously).I have not made them root nodes as then they would have to combine Home page template & master, which I believe would be repitive for client.

Comment: now , i would like to know how do i get the banners or texts saved in these different folders. i.e. how would i provide the path in xsl macro for website1 and for website2. Please advise.Kind Regards, Sarah

Comment: @brainbox - Hi, Sarah. Method 1 should be fine for what you need to achieve. You'll only need one tree in the Content section, so there's no duplicate content. Then have one master template that calls two macros (one for header, one for footer). Then use the XSLT `choose` logic to display the appropriate content. You can upload images to the media section and just write text inline with the XSLT code. If the banners and footer text need to be content managed by the client, you could always create properties for each of the sites on your root site node and reference them that way.

Comment: Yeah,the contents for different websites will be  managed by client. This is what i am confused about.So,for example,I have two folders website1_header & website2_header (in contents),in which the client has uploaded banner image. what will be the XSLT code that will retrieve particular banner for lets say , website1?.Please advise.

Comment: @brainbox - I've updated the answer to show how you can retrieve the respective banners (see method 1 again). Just remember to replace the node IDs and rename the property on the website node in my code to whatever you called it. In my example I just called it `banner`. It's not the most elegant solution to the problem, but should do the trick if you're a beginner in XSLT.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your support and help. I have implemented this code, however, my banner images are not displayed, when printed the Node and NodeID, it says that the content are not published. Please advise. Kind Regards

Comment: @brainbox - Did you publish the nodes in the content tree? Clicking on the `Save` button won't publish by default, so you'll need to click on the `Save and Publish` button next to it.

Comment: @brainbox - Well, `Node` and `NodeID` aren't recognised nodes/attributes. Try the following `<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1046)/@id" />` or `<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1046)/@nodeName" />` replacing the number with the actual node id you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks again Goran.  I have used the following code and it worked if i make the websiteOne Directory, root directory.  'code'<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/banner, 0)" />

     <xsl:if test="$media">
        <img src="{$media/umbracoFile}" alt="{$media/altText}" />
     </xsl:if>'code'
However,the problem is I want my route node to be Home, which has home template and is also sub template of master. I want my macro to fetch data from websiteOne and websiteTwo but still keeping the Home node the root node.

Comment: @brainbox - That's the whole point of using the `GetXmlNodeById(...)` function. It will allow you to reference nodes in another part of the tree, or even another tree. Whilst `$currentPage` would only you to access the currentPage node or any other node part of the same tree, through XPath. Really not sure what to suggest as the code I've supplied in the answer was working when I set up a test. Did you change the Ids in my code to the Ids of `websiteOne` and `websiteTwo`? Those will be found on the `Properties` tab of the respective nodes.

Comment: Hi Goran, Thank you very much for your help. It really did help. Though I could not get the banner the right way (as it only displays a number and not the image, part of the reason may be the media picker does not pick the banner image but i have to use rich text editor) . Anyhow, it is working now based on different domains, sub pages etc.

Comment: Now as I am totally novice for webdevelopment and this is my first project. The question now is what i need to do , to divert multiple website to one umbraco.  For example, i have website1.com and website2.com. What steps should i take?. I understand i need to add domain names in manage host names, but what else i need to do. Do I need to add it to IIS and how do i do that? Please provide step by step guide. Please note that I only want to use only one Home node, i.e. all the contents are same apart from banner or images etc.
Regards
Sarah

Comment: Thanks very much ... things are pretty much on right track now :). Regards , brainbox